# How to find potential AD-groupname and OU-structure dependencies of eco-systems?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, groups, organizational-unit

Currently we are in the process of redesigning our AD infrastructure. I am pretty concerned about the possible impact a change of several group- or OU-names might have to our eco-systems (like IAM relevant software, etc). I want to ensure that there are no unknown dependencies.

So what would be the best way to determine which IP addresses/hosts or scripts/processes are dependent on the existent OU-structure and group-names?

I was thinking about monitoring LDAP queries using wireshark. But that might be too inconvenient. What other possibilities do you see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend iterative changes.  Create the new desired structure (groups first) and add existing items there.  You can then unit test removing the legacy groups one or two at a time, while knowing exactly where to look if things break.

A cut-over approach will likely be a huge headache for an organization of any size.

I will say that OUs are **probably** easier, if only because they are mostly a target for Group Policies.  GPMC and RSOP tools are well suited to sorting out hierarchy before such a venture.

You should definitely include all technology teams in the effort, as someone invariably targeted SharePoint user sync or something to a specific OU or branch (to keep real users separate from service accounts, etc.)

I am not aware of a tool that will do this for you.  I would also not trust any tool to do 100% of the work.

Comment: Quick question, why would you create new ones in stead of renaming? Renaming an OU in AD is actually quite [safe](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/d0929cbb-b635-4f6c-b6cf-d53e331bd927/is-there-any-impact-by-renaming-ou-in-ads?forum=winserverDS) and will not break any connected policies.

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with renaming a group, but I had it in my mind that the OP was describing a "rip and replace" type of operation.  My concern is reusing a group perpetuates the chance that its purpose isn't fully understood.

Answer (score 2):

This is very hard to find out.

I'm not entirely sure if it's possible to find out if a particular group is being called.
Regardless, even if you did manage to find out if a specific group is being used, and from where, most applications don't actually use the group name. They use the SID of the group.

Chances are if you were to find out exactly where all the calls are coming from, you still wouldn't be able to find out if the call was done using the SID, or if the application was poorly written and actually utilizes the group name.

See this [related post](https://serverfault.com/questions/503103/active-directory-does-renaming-a-security-group-also-change-the-name-of-all-ins).

Comment: One approach I have just learned about would be a GPO on the DCs using `Advanced Audit DS Access` and then define SACLs on the relevant OUs.